# Xamarin android project fails to build after installing Xamarin.Google.Android.ODML.Image -Version 1.0.0.2-beta1

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-mlkit

I'm trying to include the Xamarin.Google.MLKit.BarcodeScanning in my Xamarin android project. The Xamarin.Google.Android.ODML.Image is one of the dependencies which is a pre-release version. When I install it, it also installs the Xamarin.Build.Download (version=0.11.3).

When I try to build the project afterwards, it give this error => Invalid item ID image-1.0.0-beta1

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: much more details are needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new project to add the `Xamarin.Google.Android.ODML.Image` nuget package lastest versoin `1.0.0.2-beta1`. And it also installed the Xamarin.Build.Download (version=0.11.3).

When I build the project, there was no error. So you can also try to download the lastest version instead of the `1.0.0-beta1`.

In addition, you can create a new project to test or clean and rebuild your project. I used visual studio 2022 17.4 preview 2.1. The TargetSdk is Android api 33.

Comment: Thanks. I created a new project and all the mentioned packages were installed and project were built fine. What has gone wrong for my previous project was I previously installed the 1.0.0-beta1 package and uninstalled and then again installed the 1.0.0.2-beta1. I guess it has not been cleaned properly that's why maybe I was getting an error about 1.0.0-beta1.

Answer (score 0):

I had to check the box "Include prerelease" within the NuGet Package Manager. This allowed me to install Xamarin.Google.Android.ODML.Image 1.0.0.7-beta1